# What is the name for wireframing in the browser?

Tags: website-design, layout, wireframe

I am working on quite a large web project and I am thinking that I will first design a series of wireframes in Sketch... but then once those are approved, I plan to build the wireframes using Bootstrap and have a few static pages so that the client can navigate around.

The next step will then be to design the look & feel (so back to Sketch at that point).

So I'm wondering, how do I differentiate (in terms of naming) between wireframing in an app such as Sketch / Illustrator... and wireframing in a browser e.g. Bootstrap?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Wireframing in an app is called **Wireframe**

Developing the wireframes to interactive demos (e.g.Bootstrap) is called **Prototyping**

## Edit:

Helpful prototype types from the slides @Jose mentioned in his post:

**Paper Prototypes**
Tools often used: Paper, Pen, Markers

[image]

---

**Low Fidelity Prototypes**
Tools often used: Balsamiq, Axure

[image]

---

**High Fidelity Prototypes**
Tools often used: Invision, Marvel, Sketch, Photoshop, Justinmind

[image]

---

**Functional Prototypes**
App Inventor, Origami, Framer, Twitter Bootstrap, HTML/CSS/JS

[image]

Comment: thanks! so just to clarify, the prototype would be just a skeleton of the design, without any of the branding / look & feel added to it?

Comment: @pealo86 Yes! It would be. The purpose is to let the client interact with the project and observe task flow.

Answer (score 9):

> You can use a wireframe as a prototype, but not all wireframes are prototypes.

**Wireframe** = a **diagram** that uses black and white lines only and no color.

**Prototype** = anything that helps you **test** a hypothesis. Such as,

1. will this javascript function do the job?
2. Is this layout clear enough
3. Is this UU flow optimal
4. Do users like this color palette? Typical protoypes are made with: a paper prototype with marvel app, justinmind, html code...

There is a principle that says that the higher the **fidelity** the prototype, the more accurate the feedback one gets. If you are looking for a naming convention maybe you can use the degree of fidelity to distinguish between your wireframes / prototypes.

hope that helps. Here some more examples of [types](https://www.slideshare.net/harriken/lean-ux-workshop-makers-of-barcelona-mob-agile-bcn-meetup) (slide 13 to 22) of prototypes:

Comment: This is the most correct-est answer   The distinction you're looking for as far as fidelity is concerned is `lo-fi` vs `hi-fi` prototypes. There's a great deal of fuzzy middle ground, but what the OP describes sounds clearly like a **lo-fi prototype**.

Comment: My slides have been scrapped lol

Answer (score 3):

That's called **prototyping**.

You can also use paper prototyping or creating clickable demos using apps like [Marvel App.](http://marvelapp.com)

Answer (score 0):

This is how I understand these terms in simple way

I divide this complete word into 2 words i.e. **Wire** and **Frame**. Suppose if you are sculptor and have to make a statue of say human. It would be good enough to first make skeleton of wires and wood/steel. When you do this you are actually making the **wireframe** of human.

When you are done with wireframe which in other words means you are done with shape, position and low level look and feel of the sculptor.

Similarly we draft a design for our homes as well on paper first to get an idea about our future home.

Then when you put either mud or cement over this human wireframe you try to give it exact shape, feel, expression, position etc which is other words is nothing but a **prototype**.

Experts suggest the prototyping phase should be fast so that you get enough time to discover, learn, try & measure many things. Therefore I would suggest **Axure RP, UXPIN, Balsamiq** etc as best tool to get at speed.